# SQL date format for monthly report

Tags: sql, datetime

this date format seems doesn't get the last-day records

how can we solve it, please

```
BEG_DT_TM between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
```

I expected to get a monthly report of records from the first day of the month until the last day
EX:

```
1-5-2023 to 30-5-2023
```

and so own

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used.)

Comment: If you want to get the first day of a month (and your DBMS doesn't support a first_day function) then get the last day of the month before and add 1 day to it

Comment: Looks like Oracle. Your query gives correct output for given date, but here you are using add_months(..., -1) so it shows values for previous month which is April. If you want May then remove add_months() or use 0 as parameter.

Comment: We are using Oracle DBMS, but we are developing SQL scripts and SQL Navigator, to do reports using IBM Cognos.